# How to make my own base controller publish /odom?

Tags: ros, base-odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no robot, so I must build one piece by piece. I use differential drivers ,each with a encoder.And each encoder can output two channels signal :A,B.

I can read channel A and B to aquire the speed and direction of a motor through Arduino device.

But how can I integrate the signal from the two encoders with the topic of /odom with the lowest level device Arduino? If this is done by Arduino ,I doubt the ability of an 8-bit processor.
so is there any relevent reference about it?

i have check the detail of msg /odom:

```
rosmsg show nav_msgs/Odometry 
std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
string child_frame_id
geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance pose
  geometry_msgs/Pose pose
    geometry_msgs/Point position
      float64 x
      float64 y
      float64 z
    geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation
      float64 x
      float64 y
      float64 z
      float64 w
  float64[36] covariance
geometry_msgs/TwistWithCovariance twist
  geometry_msgs/Twist twist
    geometry_msgs/Vector3 linear
      float64 x
      float64 y
      float64 z
    geometry_msgs/Vector3 angular
      float64 x
      float64 y
      float64 z
  float64[36] covariance
```

thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45370/how-to-make-my-own-base-controller-publish-/odom?/) by [bobliao](https://answers.ros.org/users/2976/bobliao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first step would be to get encoders ticks -> wheel velocity for the left and right wheel. Besides the tick count/motor revolutions this obviously depends on the wheel diameter.

Next, convert left/right velocity to translational and rotational velocity. Google should give you some simple formulas using the wheel base.

Given the measured time between two odometry readings, you now get a delta in translation and orientation that you can add to your last send odometry.

You can use this information to fill out the message.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2